# Is it possible to format number with thousands separator using fmt?

Tags: c++, fmt

Is it possible to format number with thousands separator using fmt?

e.g. something like this:

```
int count = 10000;
fmt::print("{:10}\n", count);
```

## update

I am researching fmt, so I am looking for solution that works with fmt library only, without modify locale in any way.

Comment: `std::format` is proposed for C++20

Comment: See [Thousands separator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4167029/5763413)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++: Format number with commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276826/c-format-number-with-commas)

Comment: [Print integer with thousands and millions separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17530408/995714), [How to format a number with thousands separator in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43482488/995714)

Comment: all those proposed answers have nothing to do with fmt library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer online in Russian forum:

```
int count = 10000;
fmt::print("{:10L}\n", count);
```

This prints:

```
10,000
```

The thousands separator is locale depended and if you want to change it to something else, only then you need to "tinker" with locale classes.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [fmt API reference](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#locale):

> Use the 'L' format specifier to insert the appropriate number separator characters from the locale.
> Note that all formatting is locale-independent by default.

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <locale>

int main() {
  std::locale::global(std::locale("es_CO.UTF-8"));
  auto s = fmt::format("{:L}", 1'000'000);  // s == "1.000.000"
  fmt::print("{}\n", s);                    // "1.000.000"
  return 0;
}
```